# Assigning user privileges on Synology DSM

Tags: linux, filesystems, nas, synology, privileges

I have multiple shared folders on my Synology:

1. Family
2. Photo
3. Video

Now, I have several users: **Peter**, **Andrew**, **Margaret**. I would like **Peter** to have access to all the shared folders. **Andrew** should have access only to **Family** and **Margaret** only to **Video**.

I would also like that if **Peter** creates a file in **Family**, **Andrew** should be able to edit it and delete it and vice versa. The same goes if **Peter** creates a file in **Video**, then **Margaret** should also have privilege to edit and delete it and vice versa.

In essence, if a user has a right to access a shared folder, they should have privilege to edit and delete any files in that folder or in any subfolder, even if the file was created by another user. My aim is that multiple users collaborating on some video in **Video** should be able to delete a file from that folder even if some other collaborating user created it.

What would be the ost suitable approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something in the question. Open File Station, right click on the shared folder down the left hand side, left click on properties then select "Permission" on top. That will let you add/delete/change user permissions on that folder.

Comment: Well, that's what I thought but that solves only part of that problem. If you do that, the user has privilege to access that particular shared folder. However, if another user, who also has access to that shared folder, creates a file inside, it belongs to them. So no other user can modify/delete it. What I want to achieve is that if any user who has access to a shared folder creates a file in that folder, whoever with access to that shared folder can also modify/delete it even though the file doesn't belong to them.